# WooCommerce track order submit AJAX

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, woocommerce

I am new to this Ajax thing.

What I am trying to do is submit the order tracking form & display the results with AJAX. So I tried ajax to display the results in **div track_result**

The problem is below code works fine, but the tracking results are displayed as the whole new page (with header, container & footer) inside div track_result.

I am unable to figure out to display only results (WooCommerce class) inside the div and not the whole new page.

Here is the WooCommerce form-tracking.php

```
<form action="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink( $post->ID ) ); ?>" method="post" class="track_order">

<p><?php _e( 'To track your order please enter your Order ID in the box below and press the "Track" button. This was given to you on your receipt and in the confirmation email you should have received.', 'woocommerce' ); ?></p>

<p class="form-row form-row-first"><label for="orderid"><?php _e( 'Order ID', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label> <input class="input-text" type="text" name="orderid" id="orderid" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Found in your order confirmation email.', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" /></p>
<p class="form-row form-row-last"><label for="order_email"><?php _e( 'Billing Email', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label> <input class="input-text" type="text" name="order_email" id="order_email" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Email you used during checkout.', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" /></p>
<div class="clear"></div>


<p class="form-row"><input type="submit" class="button" name="track" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Track', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" /></p>
<?php wp_nonce_field( 'woocommerce-order_tracking' ); ?>
```

**jQuery**

```
 $('.track_order').submit(function() { // catch the form's submit event
    $.ajax({ // create an AJAX call...
        data: $(this).serialize(), // get the form data
        type: $(this).attr('method'), // GET or POST
        url: $(this).attr('action'), // the file to call
        success: function(response) { // on success..
            $('.track-results').html(response); // update the DIV
        }
    });
    return false; // cancel original event to prevent form submitting
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are fetching whole data from the url which you should not.

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('from_ajax', '1');// append this to your form.

 $('.track_order').submit(function() { // catch the form's submit event
    $.ajax({ // create an AJAX call...
        data: formData, // get the form data
        type: $(this).attr('method'), // GET or POST
        url: $(this).attr('action'), // the file to call
        success: function(response) { // on success..
            $('.track-results').html(response); // update the DIV
        }
    });
    return false; // cancel original event to prevent form submitting
});
```

Now in `<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink( $post->ID ) ); ?>` this page,

check if the call is from ajax, if so dont load header and footer. Load only required view

```
if(isset($_POST['from_ajax']){
     if($_POST['from_ajax'] == 1){
         // donot load header or footer , just load required vire to display.
     }
}
```

Comment: sorry i dont understand , i am a layman , still thanks for your help !!

Comment: You have to load only required view without header and footer... For that I have passed 1 variable when making Ajax call... If the variable us 1 them don't load header r footer...

Comment: will it still display the other contents on the page other than header and footer , i just want to display class woocommerce & nothing else

Comment: in `get_permalink()`, you will be loading view rite??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96790/discussion-between-niranjan-n-raju-and-wordpress-user).